# className Not working in react native with nativewind styling

Tags: react-native, mobile, tailwind-css, styling

i am attempting to use className and nativewind stlying to style my image in this custom component but the image doesn't show up, i was able to use className with nativewind in other parts of my code, but it doesnt't seem to be working her, prehaps it is because it is a custom compontent but i am not sure, i am anyone can help.

```
import {View,Text,ScrollView,TouchableOpacity,Image} from 'react-native'
import React, {useLayoutEffect} from 'react'


const CategoryCard=({imgUrl, title})=>{
    

    return(

        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
                source={{
                    uri: imgUrl,
                }}

                className='h-7 w-7 bg-gray-300 p-4 rounded-full'

            />


            <Text>{title}</Text>

        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

export default CategoryCard
```

I tried looking into the nativewind docs and found this https://www.nativewind.dev/guides/custom-components that could have something to do with it bur i couldn't really make sense of it and couldn't apply it to my own case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your tailwind.config.js? It should include your components folder:

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar problem in a project using expo + typescript. I missed an extra step for typescript in the Nativewind docs here: https://www.nativewind.dev/getting-started/typescript

Creating an `app.d.ts` file in the root of my project with the following line fixed this for me.

```
/// <reference types="nativewind/types" />
```

Answer (score 0):

create an  `app.d.ts` file in the your rootes folder and paste this

```
/// <reference types="nativewind/types" />
```

also in you `tsconfig.json` file dont forget to include you newly created `app.d.ts` file this way

```
 "include": [
"src/**/*.ts",
"src/**/*.tsx",
"index.tsx",
"/App/**/*.ts",
"App.tsx",
"app.d.ts",
"App/**/*.tsx",],
```